# CSS lining up <div>s with table elements

Tags: html, css

I’ve been trying to incorporate these `<div>`s to line up horizontally on my website. I’ve made a template that lines up the `<div>`s correctly on codepen, but unfortunately when I paste my price card code into the template it doesn’t work properly in conjunction together, any clarification and help is much appreaciated.

```
.outer-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px #3c385c;
}

.container2,
.container3 {
  margin-left: 201px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">

  <div class="container container1">
    <div class="w-table">
      <div class="w-table-cell">
        <div class="w-container">
          <div class="w-card color-green">
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="w-title" style="cursor:default">
                <h2>
                  <font size="7px">Novice</font>
                </h2>
              </div>
              <div class="w-price" style="cursor:default">
                $4.99
                <h3>/ Week</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="container-button">
                <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" style="cursor:default">
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Weekly </span>Meal Plans
              </div>
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Personal </span>Dietary Assessment and Advice
              </div>
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Full </span>Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container container2">
          <div class="w-table">
            <div class="w-table-cell">
              <div class="w-container">
                <div class="w-card color-green">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="w-title" style="cursor:default">
                      <h2>
                        <font size="7px">Novice</font>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-price" style="cursor:default">
                      $4.99
                      <h3>/ Week</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-button">
                      <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content" style="cursor:default">
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Weekly </span>Meal Plans
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Personal </span>Dietary Assessment and Advice
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Full </span>Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="container container3">
                <div class="w-table">
                  <div class="w-table-cell">
                    <div class="w-container">
                      <div class="w-card color-green">
                        <div class="card-header">
                          <div class="w-title" style="cursor:default">
                            <h2>
                              <font size="7px">Novice</font>
                            </h2>
                          </div>
                          <div class="w-price" style="cursor:default">
                            $4.99
                            <h3>/ Week</h3>
                          </div>
                          <div class="container-button">
                            <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content" style="cursor:default">
                          <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                            <span>Weekly </span>Meal Plans
                          </div>
                          <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                            <span>Personal </span>Dietary Assessment and Advice
                          </div>
                          <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                            <span>Full </span>Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/chriskaram/pen/WZyvMx)

Comment: You’re starting a new container without properly closing all tags in the previous container. Look at the indentation of your HTML. There are several `</div>`s missing. Fix that first. Are the `.container`, `.w-table`, `.w-table-cell` etc. `<div>`s supposed to be repeated?

Comment: Yes they are, because all those segments have their own properties and css

Comment: This is the template i made that lines up correctly. https://codepen.io/chriskaram/pen/XeZQWN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some closing divs on each container section and also i've added a `float: left` to container1 which lines them up.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/DollarChills/pen/wrXaLz)

css

```
.outer-container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px #3c385c;
}
.container1 {
    float: left;
}
.container2, .container3 {
    margin-left: 201px;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer-container">

      <div class="container container1">
            <div class="w-table">
            <div class="w-table-cell">
              <div class="w-container">
                <div class="w-card color-green">

                            <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="w-title" style="cursor:default">
                      <h2><font size="7px">Novice</font></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-price" style="cursor:default">
                      $4.99
                      <h3>/ Week</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-button">
                      <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="card-content" style="cursor:default">
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Weekly </span>Meal Plans
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Personal </span>Dietary Assessment and Advice
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Full </span>Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a>
                    </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>

        <div class="container container2">
            <div class="w-table">
            <div class="w-table-cell">
              <div class="w-container">
                <div class="w-card color-green">

                  <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="w-title" style="cursor:default">
                      <h2><font size="7px">Novice</font></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-price" style="cursor:default">
                      $4.99
                      <h3>/ Week</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-button">
                      <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="card-content" style="cursor:default">
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Weekly </span>Meal Plans
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Personal </span>Dietary Assessment and Advice
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Full </span>Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a>
                    </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container container3">
            <div class="w-table">
                <div class="w-table-cell">
              <div class="w-container">
                <div class="w-card color-green">

                  <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="w-title" style="cursor:default">
                      <h2><font size="7px">Novice</font></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-price" style="cursor:default">
                      $4.99
                      <h3>/ Week</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-button">
                      <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="card-content" style="cursor:default">
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Weekly </span>Meal Plans
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Personal </span>Dietary Assessment and Advice
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                      <span>Full </span>Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for looking over the code. I wasn't aware I missed some <div>'s and I also wasn't aware that I was missing the float left on the first container.

Comment: Not a problem. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the code and removed most of the nesting to show that you can do this very simply with `display: flex;` Using flex on the parent `outer-container` will set all of its children `<div class="container">` to flex children that receive `flex-direction: row` as a default.

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Novice</h2>
    <span class="price">$4.99</span>
    <h3>/ Week</h3>
    <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up   </a>
    <span>Weekly Meal Plans</span>
    <span>Personal Dietary Assessment and Advice</span>
    <span>Full Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Novice</h2>
    <span class="price">$4.99</span>
    <h3>/ Week</h3>
    <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up   </a>
    <span>Weekly Meal Plans</span>
    <span>Personal Dietary Assessment and Advice</span>
    <span>Full Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Novice</h2>
    <span class="price">$4.99</span>
    <h3>/ Week</h3>
    <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up   </a>
    <span>Weekly Meal Plans</span>
    <span>Personal Dietary Assessment and Advice</span>
    <span>Full Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a></span>
  </div>
</div>


.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px #3c385c;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.container span {display:block;}
```

example pen: https://codepen.io/andrewchar/pen/verOaq?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the input, I've never used flex before but I should start reading more into it, I appreciate you minimizing and simplifying the code but i needed the other <div>'s and tables. This works great regardless!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="container container1">
    <div class="w-table">
      <div class="w-table-cell">
        <div class="w-container">
          <div class="w-card color-green">
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="w-title" style="cursor:default">
                <h2><font size="7px">Novice</font></h2>
              </div>
              <div class="w-price" style="cursor:default">
                $4.99
                <h3>/ Week</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="container-button">
                <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" style="cursor:default">
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Weekly </span>Meal Plans
              </div>
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Personal </span>Dietary Assessment and Advice
              </div>
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Full </span>Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container container2">
    <div class="w-table">
      <div class="w-table-cell">
        <div class="w-container">
          <div class="w-card color-green">
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="w-title" style="cursor:default">
                <h2><font size="7px">Novice</font></h2>
              </div>
              <div class="w-price" style="cursor:default">
                $4.99
                <h3>/ Week</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="container-button">
                <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" style="cursor:default">
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Weekly </span>Meal Plans
              </div>
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Personal </span>Dietary Assessment and Advice
              </div>
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Full </span>Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container container3">
    <div class="w-table">
      <div class="w-table-cell">
        <div class="w-container">
          <div class="w-card color-green">
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="w-title" style="cursor:default">
                <h2><font size="7px">Novice</font></h2>
              </div>
              <div class="w-price" style="cursor:default">
                $4.99
                <h3>/ Week</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="container-button">
                <a class="w-button" href="/meal-planner" target="_blank">Sign up </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content" style="cursor:default">
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Weekly </span>Meal Plans
              </div>
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Personal </span>Dietary Assessment and Advice
              </div>
              <div class="w-item" style="cursor:default">
                <span>Full </span>Access to the <a href="/mydietgoal-dietary-catalogue">Food Catalogue</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I think this is what you want. You forgot to close a couple of div tags.

Check the pen here: https://codepen.io/roshankrishnan7/pen/pWKJZP